# Pass file into a function

Tags: python-3.x

Here is the code I wrote:

```
def write_to (a):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        f.write('{} '.format(a[i]))
    f.write('\n')

f = open('temp.txt', 'w')
a = [2, 3, "this is a test"]

write_to(a)

f.close()
```

Should I define the function like `write_to(f, a)`?

However, when I reversed it like below:

```
def tes():
    f = open('temp.txt', 'w')
    f.write('This is in function tes()\n')

tes()
f.write('This is after calling the tes() function\n')
```

There is an error: `Name f is not defined.`

Comment: yes, definitely. Why don't you do that?

Comment: Yes, unless you want to declare a global variable

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, but `write(a)` also works. So I was wondering if the file pointer is accessible without passing to the function.

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000, is file pointer always global and can be accessed by a function without passing to it?

Comment: Huh, you're right, I just ran your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code works because `f` is *global*. At this point you could omit to pass `a` as well...

But if you put your code in another function that won't work:

```
def test():
    f = open('L:/so/temp.txt', 'w')
    a = [2, 3, "this is a test"]
    write_to(a)
    f.close()
```

now you get `NameError: name 'f' is not defined`

In your second example, you're declaring a *local* variable, then you try to access it from another context: that doesn't work. Local variables do not propagate to the global scope.

Anyway, it's a bad idea to put code other than initialization code at toplevel of the modules (if imported, the code executes), so the most common usage is to create functions: so pass the parameters instead of relying on some global resolution magic.